# Enlargement of the mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css

Are there any tips available for me to enlarge my mouse cursor while hovering over some particular object ? (Sorry I am quite low with markup languages and stylesheet, please offer advice, hints and constructive information then feel free to downvote me :-( if you wish )

Comment: Closely related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648279/cursor-256x256-px-size

Comment: Do you want to enlarge the **cursor**, or the element **underneath** the cursor?  The "cursor" is the little arrow on the screen.  Do you want a bigger arrow, or do you want the stuff on the page that the arrow points to to get bigger?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find what your after using the CSS cursor property:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

I do not believe you can resize the cursor per-say, as the browser is in control of the cursor. However you can specify your own image as the cursor via "url":

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=url%28smiley.gif%29,url%28myBall.cur%29,auto

(you may need to create a javascript workaround for old browsers that don't support URL):

Comment: Thanks, but that completely changes my cursor. I need a enlarge what is underneath my mouse.

Comment: Click the link - w3schools has some accuracy problems.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to tell the browser (or, at least, no cross-browser way) to simply make its cursor bigger. You can, however, use your own image for a cursor:

```
.your-class:hover { cursor: url(/img/your_cursor.png), pointer; }
```

According to the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property), it's supported by most browsers nowadays.

Comment: Thanks, I wish to draw a circle or a rectangle that is transparent to the background. Would you please help me ?

Comment: @Serious do you need help with implementing the CSS, or drawing the image?

Answer (score 1):

The actual appearance of the mouse cursor depends on the browser and OS configuration, there is no way to alter the default ones.

You can however, attach you custom image with the cursor (this is less than ideal but the only workaround IMO)

```
.customCursor { cursor: url(cursor.cur),default; }
```

In the above example, you're telling the browser to use your custom cursor, if not fallback to default one.